# Street address #1 & #2

Tags: soap, shipping-address

I'm working on some Magento order export using SOAP and `sales_order.info` Using the `shipping_address` I'm able to get the obejct street. However this seem to include both Street 1 and Street 2. Which is the way of extracting both street 1st line and 2nd line, as I need to pass these values as two different fields to a separate system?

I use `$shipdata['shipping_address']['street']`

Comment: I'm sure $shipdata['shipping_address']['street'] is an array. But do var_dump($shipdata['shipping_address']['street']) in your code to confirm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The street field contains street1 and street2 separated by a line break.  In order to get one or the other just explode the string by `\n`.

```
$street = explode('\n', $street);
```

You can then just pull `$street[0]` for street1 or `$street[1]` for street2.  Alternatively if you are accessing the customer address object you can just call street1 or street2 directly to do the same thing:

```
$street1 = $address->getStreet1();
$street2 = $address->getStreet2();
```

Comment: Exploade doesent work for some reason:  `code` $street = explode('\n', $shipdata['shipping_address']['street']);
echo $street[0] . '<br>';
echo $street[1] . '<br>';`code`

Comment: I can assure you it is the way the address lines are stored.

Comment: Both rows are in street[0] so for some reason it does not pickup the linebreak

Comment: Replaced '\n' with "\n" Now its working

Comment: Hi. Just in case if you need to add 2 street lines when creating address programmatically (my situation when I  came to this usefull post), just apply it like that: $address->setStreet( $streetLine1 ."\n". $streetLine2);

Comment: I am using event observer with this event "customer_address_save_after"
$address = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomerAddress();
$address->getStreet2();
Its not working

Answer (score 1):

SPLITTING CUSTOMER ADDRESS FILED: street 0 and street 1

```
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);

$street = $customerAddress->getStreet();
$street0 = strtolower($street[0]);
$street1 = strtolower($street[1]);

//set "street0" as customer address...
if($street0 == $street1){
    $customerAddress->setData('street',$street0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento's objects use a getter/setter convention where getData('field') and getField() can be used interchangeable. However, to my surprise, the getters return different values on address objects. This allows you to access the street as an array or as a concatenated string. $address->getData('street') returns a string, $address->getStreet() returns an array.

Demo on Magento EE 2.3.3

[image: getData('street') vs getStreet() return types show in IDE debug panel]